# Hg - Find tags that "cover" specific file version

Tags: mercurial, tags

We use hg to control the sources for a large project. Whenever we do a release, we tag the version in hg.

Now say I take a specific revision (where I've fixed a bug for example). I want to know which releases contain this fix, i.e. which tags "cover" this revision.

How do I find this? In hg tags seem to refer only to the tagged changeset. I remember that in ClearCase every ancestor of the tagged revision would be marked too, is there a way to see this information in hg?

Thanks!

Comment: The lazy badger hit the nail on the head, I tweaked his template to "{node} - {tags}\n" which gives me a quick view of all the versions that contain a given changeset. Brilliant!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Revsets without any additional extensions can give you something. like

`hg log -r "id(hash):tip and tag()"` or shorter and nicer (maybe) version `hg log -r "descendants(hash) and tag()"`

Just and example of shortened revset from my repo with merges after revision in question

```
>hg glog -r "descendants(c9e3b41ec78f)"
@  changeset:   65:f202d72d6397
|  tag:         tip
|  parent:      63:c778bae76563
|  user:        Alex Bream
|  date:        Wed Nov 09 21:42:50 2011 +0600
|  summary:     2-9 яюыэюёЄ№■ фю 2769
|
| o  changeset:   64:625d08492555
| |  branch:      Cleanup
| |  parent:      62:eed6619dadb8
| |  user:        Alex Bream
| |  date:        Wed Nov 09 21:38:44 2011 +0600
| |  summary:     ╟рўшёЄър яю 1-1 155
| |
o |  changeset:   63:c778bae76563
|\|  parent:      61:e7ae9e5f725a
| |  parent:      62:eed6619dadb8
| |  user:        Alex Bream
| |  date:        Wed Nov 09 21:33:22 2011 +0600
| |  summary:     Merge with Cleanup
| |
| o  changeset:   62:eed6619dadb8
| |  branch:      Cleanup
| |  parent:      59:c9e3b41ec78f
| |  user:        Alex Bream
| |  date:        Thu Mar 03 19:19:34 2011 +0500
| |  summary:     ╟рўшёЄър яю 1-1 131
| |
o |  changeset:   61:e7ae9e5f725a
| |  user:        Alex Bream
| |  date:        Thu Mar 03 05:40:34 2011 +0500
| |  summary:     2-9 яю 2745
| |
o |  changeset:   60:1393fe759096
|\|  parent:      57:a38258cac9b8
| |  parent:      59:c9e3b41ec78f
| |  user:        Alexander
| |  date:        Thu Mar 03 04:59:22 2011 +0500
| |  summary:     Merge ё ўшёЄшыъющ
| |
| o  changeset:   59:c9e3b41ec78f
| |  branch:      Cleanup
| |  user:        Alexander
| |  date:        Thu Mar 03 04:54:11 2011 +0500
| |  summary:     ╟рўшёЄър яЁюыюу яюыэюёЄ№■
| |
```

And comparing output of two forms of revsets (same output anyway)

**descendants()**

```
>hg log -r "descendants(c9e3b41ec78f)" --template "{rev}:{node|short}\n"
59:c9e3b41ec78f
60:1393fe759096
61:e7ae9e5f725a
62:eed6619dadb8
63:c778bae76563
64:625d08492555
65:f202d72d6397
```

**Direct range definition**

```
>hg log -r "id(c9e3b41ec78f):tip" --template "{rev}:{node|short}\n"
59:c9e3b41ec78f
60:1393fe759096
61:e7ae9e5f725a
62:eed6619dadb8
63:c778bae76563
64:625d08492555
65:f202d72d6397
```

Comment: I suppose this could work, but from what I gather you'd have to take each tag, trace the descendants and see if your changeset is in there?

Comment: @YMA - no, as **I** read your text you have to use reversed order - find tags **after some revset** - "... which releases contain this fix..."

Comment: My mistake. Indeed, this would give me all the tags I need. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This gives the output similar to `hg tags`:

```
hg log -r "reverse(descendants(8bb6)) and tag()" --template "{tags}\t{rev}:{node|short}\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Nearest extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NearestExtension) to find the nearest forward tag to your revision. Then, depending on your workflow, you should be able to easily deduce which other tag also contains your change.

You can also use the following to print the latest backward tag from the current revision :

```
hg log -l 1 --template "{latesttag}\n"
```

And then also deduce the "covering" tag.

Comment: {latesttag} shows tag *before* changeset, OP **asked "all after"**. FAIL

Comment: @LazyBadger Yeah, it's what I said in my answer... Once you have the last tag before (or backward to reuse my word), you can deduce the others.

Comment: Good idea, but the tags are not necessarily linear - our changeset graph looks more like a tapestry than a ladder :)