# Mercurial: Find all tags that are applied to a revision of a file

Tags: mercurial

I want to find out which tags have been applied to a certain version of a file in my mercurial repository.

This might be useful when finding a bug. Then you might want to know which other tagged release versions might also be affected by the same issue.

Is there an easy way to do this, or is my thinking still too "CVS-ish"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hg - Find tags that "cover" specific file version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8703653/hg-find-tags-that-cover-specific-file-version)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
hg log -r 'tag()' myfile.txt
```

to see all tags of myfile.txt and

```
hg log -r 'tag() and ::23' myfile.txt
```

to display all commits with tags of myfile.txt since version 23. I guess it's not exactly what you want to do but maybe it goes into the right direction.